# A matrix polynomial problem

Tags: matrices, polynomials

Could there be a degree $>1$ polynomial in $g(x)\in\Bbb K^{n\times n}[x]$ for any field $\Bbb K$ such that *any* given symmetric $A$ we have $g(A)=PAP^T$ for some permutation $P$?

Comment: What do you mean by $P'$ ? $P^T$ (which is also $P^{-1}$) ?

Comment: Where are you getting these problems? (And do you mean $g(x)$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{K}$?)

Answer (score 2):

No there cannot.

Suppose there were such a polynomial $g$. Then $g$ must satisfy
$$g(\lambda) = \lambda$$
for all $\lambda\in \mathbb{K}$. To see this, we simply let $A = \lambda I$ (any $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ will do). Then we have
$$g(\lambda I) = g(\lambda)I = P(\lambda I)P^\mathrm{T} = \lambda I.$$
Note in the last line we've used the fact that our permutation matrix $P$ is orthogonal, so $P^\mathrm{T} = P^{-1}$. This must be satisfied for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{K}$. We could let the permutation $P$ be a function of $A$ as well, and this would not change anything.